# When a question is marked as duplicated then information should also include the links back to the duplicated question

Tags: feature-request, status-norepro

When some question is marked as duplicated it shows hyperlink to the moderators/users who marked the question duplicated, but it should also show the link for that question(s) which are actually duplicated............

```
closed as exact duplicate by [Al Everett][1], [Senseful][2]♦ yesterday

This question covers exactly the same ground as earlier questions on this topic; its answers may be merged with another identical question.


  [1]: http://
  [2]: http://
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This already happens. You get "Possible Duplicate" followed by the question(s) suggested by the closers.

Take [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5723/can-i-schedule-to-send-mail-later-on-with-duration-on-gmail-closed) as an example.

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I set an e-mail to send on a timer within gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2936/can-i-set-an-e-mail-to-send-on-a-timer-within-gmail)

Comment: ok I see, and when and how the answers will be merged do you have any idea ?

Comment: @shahjapan - I'd have to try and find a merged question to answer that.